¿Como actualizar datos de una coleccion obtenida por mongoDB con datos en especifico?
Espero me puedan apoyar, estoy tratando de actualizar datos de mi colección pero con ciertos filtros, quiero actualizar mi dato descripcion si y solo si mi campo block_edition_description sea igual a true.
Esta es mi coleccion:
{
  "id": "factor-kaiser"
  "titulo": "Factor Kaiser1",
  "block_edition_title": true
}

Esta es la forma en como actualizo mis datos:
  with DBManager.get_instance().client.start_session(causal_consistency=True) as session:
    with session.start_transaction():
        main_result = is_successful_operation(
            load_collection().update_one(
                {'id': podcast_instance.id},
                {'$set': omit_attributes(podcast_instance.__dict__, ['id'])},
                upsert=True
            )
        )
        if not main_result:
            session.abort_transaction()
            return False
        session.commit_transaction()
    return True

Trate de hacerlo con arrayFilters pero no obtuve éxito, no se si lo hice mal, espero me puedan ayudar o guiar en mi error.
